# ionic change progressBar bar color in javascript

Tags: javascript, progress-bar, ionic-framework

The code below is not workING in my application

**HTML:**

```
<div class="progressBar">
    <div class="progressBarIndicator">
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.progressBar{background-color: #fff; height:20px;}
.progressBarIndicator{background-color: #000; height:20px;}
```

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
$('.progressBarIndicator').css({"background-color" : "red"});
```

Answer (score 1):

First Check, whether `jquery.min.js` is present or not.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

If yes, change your script like this way.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.progressBarIndicator').css("background-color","red");
});
</script>

$('.progressBarIndicator').css({"background-color" : "red"});
                               ^                   ^      ^
                            remove  replace with comma   Remove
```

For more info, check this [Jquery CSS Method - W3 Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/css_css.asp) & [Background CSS Using Jquery - Web Developer Forum](http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?228191-%28-id%29-css%28-background-url%28%29-%29-not-working)

My Updated Code. Do the needful changes if required.

```
<html>
    <head></head>

<body>
    <style>
        .progressBar{
          width: 100%;
          height: 20px;
          background: #fff;
          border-radius: 2px;
          border: 1px solid rgba(199, 197, 197, 1);
        }

        .progressBarIndicator{
          height: 20px;
          background: #019F45;
          overflow: hidden;
          border-radius: 2px;
        }
    </style>

    <div class="progressBar">
        <div class="progressBarIndicator">
    </div>

</body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
         $('.progressBarIndicator').css("background", "red");
    });
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry, the bar color remain the same for me
Do you have any other solution?
Thank you

Comment: you kept inside document.ready function, right ? @user5421332

Comment: Update your question with your edited code @user5421332

Comment: HTML `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script><div class="progressBar">
 <div class="progressBarIndicator">
</div>`   CSS     `.progressBar{
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 2px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(199, 197, 197, 1);
}

.progressBarIndicator{
  height: 20px;
  background: #019F45;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 2px;
}`      JAVASCRIPT   `$(document).ready(function(){
     $('.progressBarIndicator').css("background", "red");
});`

Comment: In my desktop. It's Working Mr @Yuan. Let me share my code. wait for 2 min.

Comment: I've updated my answer. See updated answer. And, do the needful changes if required @Yuan

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

HTML:

```
<div class="progressBar">
 <div class="progressBarIndicator">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.progressBar{
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 2px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(199, 197, 197, 1);
}

.progressBarIndicator{
  height: 20px;
  background: #019F45;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('.progressBarIndicator').css("background", "red");
});
```